# Fetch rest api data using aws lambda in java springboot application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

Hi I am novice to aws lambda I am trying to fetch rest api data from any dummy server using aws lambda and log it. I am not able to find relevant information using Java, only python code samples available can someone please guide me here.

I am able to find codes for handler https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/java-basic but no code for fetching rest api data using aws lambda in java

Comment: An AWS Lambda function is basically a shell for running whatever code you want. So, look for some code that fetches data (without using Lambda) and then insert that code into the Lambda function.

Comment: I put some code up for a [simple example](https://github.com/stdunbar/aws-lambda-api-gw) that is a "raw" Lambda, without the spring extras.  It calls an API and returns the results.  It can be integrated with API Gateway, HTTP or REST.  As @JohnRotenstein indicates, you can create the spring boot container around this though I question the need for a server container (spring boot) to be placed into a server container (Lambda).